# How do I join 4 tables on mysql select statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 4 tables in MySQL to join. Example

```
$select = $db->query("SELECT * 
                        FROM ads 
                       WHERE ad_pic='1' 
                         AND ad_status = '1' 
                    ORDER BY ad_id DESC LIMIT 0,4");

while ($fetch = $db->fetch($select)) {

    $iquery = $db->query("SELECT * 
                            FROM images 
                           WHERE img_ads_id = '" . intval($fetch['ad_id']) . "' 
                             AND img_status = '1' 
                           LIMIT 1");
    $thumb = $db->fetch($iquery);

    $uselect = $db->query("SELECT * 
                             FROM users 
                            WHERE user_id = '".intval($fetch['ad_userid'])."' 
                              AND user_status = '1' 
                            LIMIT 1");
    $ufetch = $db->fetch($uselect);

    $cselect = $db->query("SELECT * 
                             FROM category 
                            WHERE cat_slug = '".safe_func($fetch['ad_category'])."' 
                            LIMIT 1");
    $cfetch = $db->fetch($cselect);         

}
```

I want to know the way to join these in one select statement.

---

```
ads table

ad_id   ad_userid   ad_category
-------------------------------
1       2           5

images table

img_id  img_ads_id  
-------------------------------
1       1         

users table

user_id     user_name
-------------------------------
2           John

category table 

cat_id   cat_name
-------------------------------
5        Vehicles
```

Comment: can you give us the portion of the schema that is relevant to the four tables you want to join?

Comment: Are there 1-to-1 relations between ads and images? Between ads and users? Between ads and categories? (I'm guessing yes.)

Comment: as Brian asked, give us full schema. need to know the foreign keys and private keys in each of those tables to find out how are they related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM ads AS a
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.img_ads_id = a.ad_id AND i.img_status = 1
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = a.ad_userid AND u.user_status = 1
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_slug = a.ad_category
WHERE a.ad_pic = 1
AND a.ad_status = 1
ORDER BY a.ad_id DESC
LIMIT 0,4
```

If an ad must have an image, user, or category, you may use a JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN. If an ad can have more than one image, user, or category, you will need a more complex query.