# Mysql Join tables - best practice?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 5 tables

1. Users Personal Data (users _ record=120000).
2. Users where work (users_positions _ record=150000).
3. Organization (organizations _ record=2500).
4. Divisions (divisions _ record=3500).
5. Positions (positions _ record=4500).

I want to JOIN these tables, but what is the best query?

I write this query, but it is very slow:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    p.* 
  FROM
    `user_positions` p 
    LEFT JOIN `organizations` u_o 
      ON u_o.`id` = p.`org_title` 
    LEFT JOIN `divisions` u_d 
      ON u_d.`id` = p.`division` 
    LEFT JOIN `positions` u_p 
      ON u_p.`id` = p.`position` 
      WHERE u_o.`status` = 1 
  GROUP BY p.`PRN`) u_a 
  LEFT JOIN `users` u 
    ON u.`PRN` = u_a.`PRN`
```

Example - Simple Structure

```
table users
-- PRN --- FirstName --- Age....
-- 001 --- david --- 24 ....
-- 052 --- george --- 27 ....


table users_positions
-- PRN --- Organization_ID --- Division_ID --- Positionn_ID....
-- 001 --- 1 --- 5 --- 1....
-- 001 --- 2 --- 10 --- 5....
-- 052 --- 1 --- 1 --- 1....

table organizations
-- ID --- Name ....
-- 1 --- test 1 ....
-- 2 --- test 2 ....

table divisions
-- ID --- Name --- Age....
-- 1 --- IT Department ....
-- 5 --- Sale Department ....
-- 10 --- Administration Department ....

table positions
-- ID --- Name --- Age....
-- 1 --- Programmer ....
-- 5 --- Manager ....
```

Comment: Any indexes on these columns?

Comment: This question is being asked previously


just go with the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227313/how-do-i-join-4-tables-on-mysql-select-statement)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with `GROUP BY` here. You probably don't need it or could do it differently (you're not using any aggregate function). [MySQL's `GROUP BY` behaviour](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html) can lead to bad habits and/or [incorrect results](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/).

Comment: "users" relation are with "user_positions" with PRN. PRN in "users" is a unique and not unique in "user_positions"

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are using a `GROUP BY` on your query.  A `GROUP BY` is typically used when you have an aggregate function in your query. But I would say you might be able to use the following:

```
select *
from users u
left join users_positions up
  on u.PRN = up.PRN
left join positions p
  on up.id = p.position
left join organizations o
  on p.org_title = o.id
left join divisions d
  on p.division = d.id
```

Edit, with your sample data that you provided, here is a sample of a query that you can use:

```
select u.prn,
  u.firstname,
  u.age,
  o.name orgName,
  p.name positionName,
  d.name divisionName
from users u
left join users_positions up
  on u.PRN = up.PRN
left join organizations o
  on up.Organization_ID = o.id
left join positions p
  on up.Positionn_ID = p.id
left join divisions d
  on up.Division_ID = d.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7434b/9)

The result of this query is:

```
| PRN | FIRSTNAME | AGE | ORGNAME | POSITIONNAME |              DIVISIONNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 001 |     david |  24 |  test 1 |   Programmer |           Sale Department |
| 001 |     david |  24 |  test 2 |      Manager | Administration Department |
| 052 |    george |  27 |  test 1 |   Programmer |             IT Department |
```

If you only want to return one organization, etc per user then you need to decide how you will determine the correct result to return. For example, if you only want to return the `max(Organization_ID)` per user, then you can use something similar to this:

```
select u.prn,
  u.firstname,
  u.age,
  o.name orgName,
  p.name positionName,
  d.name divisionName
from users u
left join
(
  select max(Organization_ID) Organization_ID, PRN
  from users_positions
  group by PRN
) up1
  on u.PRN = up1.PRN
left join users_positions up2
  on up1.PRN = up2.prn
  and up1.Organization_ID = up2.Organization_ID
left join organizations o
  on up2.Organization_ID = o.id
left join positions p
  on up2.Positionn_ID = p.id
left join divisions d
  on up2.Division_ID = d.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7434b/8)

Result:

```
| PRN | FIRSTNAME | AGE | ORGNAME | POSITIONNAME |              DIVISIONNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 001 |     david |  24 |  test 2 |      Manager | Administration Department |
| 052 |    george |  27 |  test 1 |   Programmer |             IT Department |
```

Comment: "users" relation are with "user_positions" with PRN.
PRN in "users" is a unique and not unique in "user_positions"

Comment: @David... there are other ways to get a single records from a table for each user, applying a `GROUP BY` is not the best way of doing that.  If you post your full table structure, sample data and then the desired result of the query you will probably get more feedback on how best to solve your problem.

Comment: example: i work in 5 positions. In users table are 1 record, and users_positions table - 5 record

Comment: With your GROUP BY, that should return one row for each p.PRN anyway. If you're relatively new to MySQL, try to use the ["only full group by" mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), this should prevent you from taking bad habits.

Comment: @David... right I understand that you have a one-to-many relationship between your tables but using `GROUP BY` to return the data is not the best route to do this.

Comment: @David... the way you're using `GROUP BY` simply means it's going to take one of the one-to-many rows for each p.PRN, in a non-deterministic way. This is probably not what you want. (This MySQL "feature" can lead to bad SQL code...)

Comment: @David... can you edit your original question and post the table structures, some sample data and the desired result from your query?

Comment: @bruno - Because - if i want to search concrete position, i will add in where corresponding conditional.
Other case I will get count of Employed users

Comment: @David... it's quite clear that `GROUP BY` isn't what you should use here, and that it only works because of MySQL's extension here.

Comment: @David... I'm not sure exactly which conditions you would want to use, but `GROUP BY` is for aggregates, and you should put all and only the columns you group by (+ aggregate functions) with it (see links I posted earlier). Here, you're not aggregating anything, merely trying to get one row out of many. Writing out the condition explicitly will at least make the query deterministic (and quite possibly more efficient).

Comment: @David... please see my edit.  If you only want to return one record per user, then you need to determine which one to return.

Comment: @David... then what do you want?